# Count arrays in 2D array where some field is non-empty

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, array-filter

I have an array of arrays:

```
$array = array (
"text1" => array("link" => "link1.php", "value" => $value1),
"text2" => array("link" => "link2.php", "value" => $value2),
.......
"text9" => array("link" => "link9.php", "value" => $value9)
);
```

I would like to count the number of arrays for which the `"value"` field is not null.

I tried this:

```
count(array_filter($array));
```

but obviously it returns 9, even if some of the `$valueN` variables are empty.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can apply a callback to your `array_filter()` call, just check if `value` isset / 0 and filter them out.

Comment: Take a look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php there is everything documented with some nice examples.

Comment: Or use array_column as argument for array_filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract values from a multidimensional array. So to get an array containing just the value fields you can use:

```
$values = array_column($array, "value");
```

If you want to just get the count of the truthy values you can then use:

```
count(array_filter(array_column($array, "value");
```